# LTSpice noise simulation with custom noise voltage source

Tags: noise, ltspice, simulation

I'm trying to simulate noise of a circuit in LTSpice.

I need to add custom white-noise voltage sources to the circuit, but when I do a noise simulation using the ".noise" command I don't see the contribution of these sources in the output.

I can't share my actual circuit but I created this example which shows my problem;

[image]

However when I simulate transient response I see the noise:

[image]

So the question is; How do I include custom noise voltage sources in the noise simulation?

Or am I forced to use transient simulation and then calculate the RMS voltage of the output?

Comment: I think that you're trying to do a "noise" simulation (with a random signal) in the time domain (your 2nd plot shows time on the X-axis). The .noise statement doesn't work like that, .noise is a **small signal analysis** similar to the .ac analysis. Have you read: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/Noise-Analysis-Using-LTspice-Tutorial/ ?

Comment: `white()` (and its cousins, `rand()` and `random()`) is a time-domain function, so it has no effect in the frequency domain. See Vinzent's answer for a common solution.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm aware that noise is a small signal analysis similar to .ac.. This is the simulation I was intending. The reason for showing the second plot (transient) was to show that the white-noise source was working in the time domain. I understand now that the white(..) function only works in the time domain..

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for clarifying that those functions only work in the time domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is (most easily) achieved in LTSpice by using a resistor as input to a voltage-controlled-voltage-source (VCVS).**

[image]

Comment: ...where the level can be calculated as the [Johnson noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I include custom noise voltage sources in the noise simulation?*

When doing an AC analysis, it scans the spectrum with a sinewave source hence your noise source is irrelevant and ignored in an AC analysis. If you want to see the spectral effects that the noise creates you'll need to run a transient analysis then, set up a Fourier analysis based on the transient results (between two points in time or the whole transient response).

Comment: @Vinzent you are asking the wrong person - I am only reporting what I find to be true about simulators.